# how to make ul scroll down when full?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a `<ul>` defined as

```
<ul id="messages">

</ul>
```

I do not have any `<li>` items defined in html but in my javascript I use jquery to add `<li>` items to the `<ul>`

```
$("#messages").append("<li>" + string + "</li>");
```

When I keep adding messages it does not automatically scroll down to the newest added li items when it has too many li items to fit the screen. How do I get the li to scroll down?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use CSS to achieve this:

```
ul {
overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

You also need to give the UL a max-height for this to work.

Comment: I tried ul{max-height: 36.5em; overflow-y: scroll; } did not work

Comment: interesting... it worked for me. Maybe using px would work better, being static

Answer (score 0):

You're looking to automatically have the page scroll down to a li when it's added?

You need to use jQuery and javascript to get the `<li>`'s offset from the top of the window. Then set scroll the window to that position.

```
var offset = $('li').offset().top;

$('body').scrollTop(offset);
```

[Here's an example](https://jsfiddle.net/1rf1eawt/)

If you want to animate it use something like this:

```
$('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: offset
}, 1000);
```

Comment: I am not trying to have the page scroll, I am trying to make the ul scroll down

Comment: The solution I presented targets the body. If you want a `ul` specifically to be scrolled you need to target it instead. You also need a set height and `overflow: auto` to have a scrollable container. Here's a revised fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/1rf1eawt/1/

Answer (score 0):

I've done it on a click event as you haven't really said when you adding the item

HTML you need to get working example is

```
<button id="click">Click me</button>
<ul id="messages">

</ul>
```

JQuery is

```
 $(document).ready(function (){
        $("#click").click(function (){ 
            $("#messages").append("<li>pow</li>");
            //$(this).animate(function(){
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $("#messages li").last().offset().top
                }, 2000);
            //});
        });
    });
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Truezplaya/phncn241/2/)